# "xorriso" package

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I am installing a video editing program on 20.04 Focal Fossa but it seems that the package xorriso is missing to end  the installation sucessfully, does anyone know what to write on the terminal in order to install this package or where to download it?

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get install xorriso
```

At least for 18.04LTS it is available

```
$ apt install --print-uris xorriso 2> /dev/null
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libburn4 libisoburn1 libisofs6 libjte1
Suggested packages:
  jigit cdck
...
```

Please post feedback

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you

Comment: It's available in 20.04, too.

Comment: @Lenny - For a better askubuntu, please remember voting/accepting whenever you find something useful and/or which solves your problem.